# Way to bypass a bot sending a reminder

Tags: discord.js

I made it so if you ping the owner my bot sends a message saying "Dont ping the owner" but some people are allowed to ping the owner and i want to know a way to bypass the bot sending that message only for certain people And ***defining the people through their ID's***

Here's the code for the "Dont ping the owner" thingy

```js
const ownerId = "485705485757186050";
```

Thats defining ownerId, `485705485757186050` being the owner's ID

```js
client.on("message", async message => {
    if (message.author.bot) return false;

    if (message.mentions.has(ownerId)) {
        message.reply(`dont ping the owner`);
    };
});
```

And thats the actual message the bot sends

Please help me do this

Comment: What are the conditions to bypass? Are only certain people or role holders allowed?

Comment: Id rather have it be ID although i could make a role that could bypass if i can get code for that, that would definitely work

Comment: The answer for both of those cases can go in different directions. Once you've decided, edit your goal into the question.

Comment: Thank you very much, I will choose ID im editing it now

Answer (score 1):

Have a string array hold the id's of people who can bypass ping restraints

```js
const bypassIds = ['id1', 'id2', 'id3'];
```

Apply the logic in which if `message.author.id` is in `bypassIds` (Checked by using [Array#includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)): Do not reply.

```js
if (message.mentions.has(ownerId) && !bypassIds.includes(message.author.id)) {
   message.reply(`dont ping the owner`);
};
```

Comment: i put the const bypassids at the top of the code and where do i put the other part of the code?

Comment: Replace you current if-statement, you should see the resemblance